# How do I connect a smart contract to the frontend?

Tags: frontend

I know this question has been asked so many times and i know its a stupid question. But I am just unable to figure out how do i show information from the smart contract abi on the front end of the website.

For instance I want to show how many additional tokens are gained by wallet for holding this token.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in connecting smart contracts to websites, I recommend using Web3. Take a look at documentation: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/index.html

If you have a more specific question, feel free to ask.